# Modal is not showing

Tags: javascript, reactjs, bootstrap-modal

Im following [this](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components/modal/#tooltip) tutorial on bootstrap modal for react. This is the code i have:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Modal } from 'react-bootstrap';
import { Button } from 'react-bootstrap';
import { Popover } from 'react-bootstrap';
import { OverlayTrigger } from 'react-bootstrap';
import { Tooltip } from 'react-bootstrap';

class Login extends React.Component {
  constructor(props, context) {
    super(props, context);

    this.state = {
      show: false
    };

    this.handleShow = this.handleShow.bind(this);
    this.handleClose = this.handleClose.bind(this);
  }

  handleClose() {
    this.setState({ show: false });
  }

  handleShow() {
    console.log("Show")
    this.setState({ show: true });
  }

  render() {
    const popover = (
      <Popover id="modal-popover" title="popover">
        very popover. such engagement
      </Popover>
    );
    const tooltip = <Tooltip id="modal-tooltip">wow.</Tooltip>;

    return (
      <div>
        <p>Click to get the full Modal experience!</p>

        <Button bsStyle="primary" bsSize="large" onClick={this.handleShow}>
          Launch demo modal
        </Button>

        <Modal show={this.state.show} onHide={this.handleClose}>
          <Modal.Header closeButton>
            <Modal.Title>Modal heading</Modal.Title>
          </Modal.Header>
          <Modal.Body>
            <h4>Text in a modal</h4>
            <p>
              Duis mollis, est non commodo luctus, nisi erat porttitor ligula.
            </p>

            <h4>Popover in a modal</h4>
            <p>
              there is a{' '}
              <OverlayTrigger overlay={popover}>
                <a href="#popover">popover</a>
              </OverlayTrigger>{' '}
              here
            </p>

            <h4>Tooltips in a modal</h4>
            <p>
              there is a{' '}
              <OverlayTrigger overlay={tooltip}>
                <a href="#tooltip">tooltip</a>
              </OverlayTrigger>{' '}
              here
            </p>

            <hr />

            <h4>Overflowing text to show scroll behavior</h4>         
          </Modal.Body>
          <Modal.Footer>
            <Button onClick={this.handleClose}>Close</Button>
          </Modal.Footer>
        </Modal>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Login;
```

My issue is that when i click on the "Launch demo modal" - button the modal is not shown. I checked to see in the console if the boolean value for "show" is set to true when clicking which it is but somehow the modal is not shown anyway.

This is the entry-point for the application:

```
import Login from './Components/Modal/Login';
class App extends Component {

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">       
        <Login/>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

I have tried to figure it out for hours now but i have no idea. I even used the exact same code as the tutorial at one point but with no luck. Any help is appretiated.

Comment: Tagor, do you have any error on your browser console? this code works perfectly for me. Do you have the bootstrap css imported?

Comment: @tagor you forgot to add cdn css links. which i have pasted in answer. plz add those to index.html page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot to add style.css files. add below links to your index.html file .

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

EDIT 1:
or without CDN (on your index.html)

```
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css';
```

Comment: This works, thank you. I hade the links actually, but they where for bootstrap 4. Which apperantely did not work ...

Answer (score 0):

You can show modal using && operator with state like below. I have removed show prop to modal. Try below approach it will work

```
   {this.state.show && (
            <Modal onHide={this.handleClose}>
              ...... // place remaining code here
            </Modal>
    )}
```

Comment: this is not necessary, the modal should have enougth with his 'show' prop to render the modal.

Comment: You mostly handle such scenarios using && operator or ternary operator(other answer) in React. This is how I do.

Comment: you can have conditional render if you need to show or not a component, but react-bootstrap Modal have this logic. If you put the modal inside a conditional rendering like that, you will have this logic twice.

Comment: i checked on my local. face same issue as @tagor. just added cdn link to index.html made it workable.

Comment: I put Tagor's Login component on a create-react-app with react-bootstrap, and it works perfectly, so I supose that the problem is not about the code or render method but about the css import or the bootstrap implementation.

Comment: @daniel agree with you, bootstrap has that flexibility. You can also do as I suggested using conditional render.

Comment: Yes you can, but I think is not a good practice, because you are replacing the component logic. But yes you're right, this works too.

Comment: Thanks but this wasnt the issue. But to add to your discussion, what i find is cleanest for conditional rendering (for example displaying different pages) is to have a component variable currentPage that is continously rendered in the entry point component. The children would just use a callback to change what component currentPage is.

Answer (score 0):

It may be useful to take a look at [Conditional Rendering With React](https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html)

:-)

```js
render () {
  return (
    <div>
      {this.state.show ? /*Your component*/ : null /*Or another component*/}
    </div>
  )
}
```

*side note* : Taking this approach means that your `Modal` component is not instantiated in the first place is `this.state.show` is false which could be beneficial application speed.
If you pass a `show prop` into your `Modal` this implies the `Modal` is being instantiated and some un needed logic is being applied whithin.